# Validator.validateValue ignores validation when beanType is an interface (hibernate-validator-6.0.18)

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I have created a library that contains only Interfaces that model domain objects. These interfaces have (class, property, method, and constructor level) constraints I want to test.

For example:

```
public interface User {
    @NotNull
    @Email
    String getEmail();
}
```

I want to test the constraints are getting applied correctly, so I have written some tests. However, I get unexpected behavior.

```
class UserTest {
    @Test
    void thisTestFails() {
        Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> violations = validator.validateValue(User.class, "email", null);
        assertEquals(1, violations.size());
    }

    @Test
    void thisTestPasses() {
        Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<UserImpl>> violations = validator.validateValue(UserImpl.class, "email", null);
        assertEquals(1, violations.size());
    }

    private static class UserImpl implements User {
        @Override
        public String getEmail() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Hibernate completely ignores validation when the argument provided for `Class<T> beanType` is an interface.
I do not want to create concrete classes just to test these interfaces. Is this the expected behavior or a bug in Hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior. The Bean Validation spec defines that constraints can be defined in interfaces or classes, but what is validated is the state of property that follows the Java Beans conventions.

An interface can define a getter method that is implemented by a class, but it hasn't the property itself.

That are the relevant parts of the specification:

> **5.1.1. Object validation**
>
> Constraint declarations can be applied to a class or an interface. Applying a constraint to a class or interface
> expresses a validation over **the state of the class or the class
> implementing the interface**.
>
> **5.1.2. Field and property validation**
>
> Constraint declarations can be applied on both fields and properties
> for the same object type. The same constraint should however not be
> duplicated between a field and its associated property (the constraint
> validation would be applied twice). It is recommended for objects
> holding constraint declarations to adhere to a single state access
> strategy (either annotated fields or properties).
>
> When a field is annotated with a constraint declaration, field access
> strategy is used to access the state validated by such constraint.
>
> When a property is annotated with a constraint declaration, property
> access strategy is used **to access the state validated by such
> constraint**.

It's true that the validateValue method doesn't require an instance, so theoretically it could test the constraints of an interface. But note that the class parameter, it's a `beanType`, and the type of a bean needs to be a class, as an interface has no constructors.

Note the difference with the method `getConstraintsForClass` also from `Validator` that explicitly states that can get the constrains declared on an interfaces:

> class or interface type evaluated

While the class parameter of `validateValue`:

> the bean type

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you point me to the part of the spec that mentions this?

Comment: I added them to the answer.